# B+ Tree in DBMS

Tags: database, indexing, tree, b-tree

I was trying to implement B+ tree for an index in DBMS.
I read the definition of index in Ramakrishnan's book and it says:

> One idea is to create a second file with one record per page in the
>   original (data)file, of the form (first key on page, pointer to page),
>   again sorted by the key attribute.

And he provided this slide as well:
[image: B+ Tree Example]

I believe that the leaf nodes are equivalent to the pages. In the picture, the child nodes do not even include 13, 17, and 30 in the root node.
How could 13,17, and 30 be the first key on pages if there are no such keys on pages?

It looks like this picture does not follow the statement above(first key on the page, pointer to page) and I got confused. Could I get the exact meaning of the statement?

Comment: As you provided only a short excerpt: It looks like the quote is only a *small* part of the *motivation*, not the actual description of the data structure. In this case: Yes, the image shows the final product, which is not the same as the idea we had in between.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My purpose of this question was not to point out an inconsistency, but getting some idea on implementing this. Following question is: How could I get the addresses of the corresponding child nodes? Should I go over whole pages in a data file when I construct an index file?

Comment: If the book is any good, it should be perfectly clear by reading he descriptions provided by it. However: B-Trees are not dumb page listings but medium elaborate data structures. Determining of such things as addresses of nodes usually happens during the execution of specific procedures designed to properly update the data. (Likely `insert` or `add` and `remove` or `delete`)